# MVC3 conditional row styling but also CSS tiger striping

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set some rows in a table with a specific css style based on a property of the item being bound. With CSS I've applied tiger striping, this new css style I want to apply should be *in addition to* the existing striping.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr @if(item.IsComplete { class="complete"})>
```

and the tiger striping is achieved with:

```
table tr:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background-color: #90b2d3;
    color: white;
}
```

So every other row should be a light blue with white text but any row where the item `IsComplete` should have the 'complete' css style added to it.

```
.complete {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

which is simply to make it appear greyed out and 'complete'.

However as my code currently stands I get a `parser error`

> Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Which I don't understand, the `<tr>` is present in my first code block, and the `@ IsComplete` razor syntax *should* just be conditionally including a css class.

I am aware that this approach does mean that if the tiger striping were to colour a row **and** the `IsComplete` property were to add a css class that only one of them would be used - I was hoping to deal with that after figuring out what's wrong with the syntax here. Though if there is a way to get both classes applied (should they be required) that would be awesome.

Comment: View your HTML source. I suspect you have a tag that looks like `<trclass="complete">`

Comment: I'm just getting a `YSOD` with the `Encountered end tag "tr"...` message. But I tried added a space between the `tr` and the `class` and removing all other content. I never get to see the generated html just the YSOD

Comment: Oh I think I see it now. You need "@class", not "class". Class is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Darin's advice I've implemented a `Custom HTML helper`, which I'm sharing as it answers the main question, though it replaces the tiger striping - so there's more work to be done so the original tiger striping is respected and this adds to an existing class

```
public static MvcHtmlString ConditionalCss(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                           bool isCompleted, string CssClass)
    {
        var Css = String.Empty;
        if (isCompleted)
            Css = string.Format("class=\"{0}\"", CssClass);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(Css);
    }
```

now the call inside the `foreach` is simplified to

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr @Html.ConditionalCss(item.IsComplete, "complete")>
```

Which gives me a bit of flexibility; I can supply any css class and condition for which case the css should be added

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<tr@(Html.Raw(item.IsComplete ? " class=\"complete\"" : ""))>
```

or write a custom HTML helper to avoid the tag soup.

Comment: This throws > Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. You forgot to close the opening `{` for your `foreach` loop. This has nothing to do with the `<tr>` element.

Comment: I've been using MVC for about 3 days now... It's not all that clear to me. As far as I can see the braces are paired up?

Comment: Since you haven't shown your code I cannot tell what's paired and what not, sorry. I cannot read your mind.

Comment: Apologies, mind-reading a muddled mind like mine would be some skill! I'd used the `Html.Raw` code suggestion you provided to replace the 2nd line in my original code block, I'd assumed it was a straight swap and that the `Html.Raw` function was a more appropriate approach than my conditional `if`. The helper seems a much nicer approach, just need to refine that so the `nth-child` css rules are also respected to close this issue